# Kivy: How To Solve Crashing App When Using Python Functions

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, numpy, kivy

I'm trying to combine the GUI features of Kivy with the Python function I wrote. But whenever I call the function onto one of my `Screen` classes, the whole app crashes and consumes my memory and cpu usage.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is get the `global where` variable from the comparison `fn_compare` function that involves two csv files. Then, I intend to use that variable in three  other functions. The `fn_verifier` function is to use that `global where` variable to verify with any of the 26 letters of the alphabet what matches it, then it plays a sound.

```
class Identifier:
    def fn_compare(self): 
        count=1
        while (count>0):
            livecsv=np.genfromtxt("lettera.csv", delimiter=",", skip_header=1, filling_values=np.nan, dtype=int, case_sensitive=True, deletechars='', replace_space=' ')
            refcsv=np.genfromtxt("refcsv1.csv", delimiter=",", skip_header=1, filling_values=np.nan, dtype=int, case_sensitive=True, deletechars='', replace_space=' ')
            A=np.array(livecsv)
            B=np.array(refcsv)
            D=B - A[-1]
            match= B[np.abs(D).sum(axis=1).argmin()]
            global where
            where=match[0]
            time.sleep(1)
            count = count + 1
    def fn_verify(self):
        global where
        var=where
        if var==1:
            A=playsound('audio-alphabet/A.wav',True)
            return A
        elif var==2:
            B=playsound('audio-alphabet/B.wav',True)
            return B
        elif var==3:
            C=playsound('audio-alphabet/C.wav',True)
            return C
        elif var==4:
            D=playsound('audio-alphabet/D.wav',True)
            return D
        elif var==5:
            E=playsound('audio-alphabet/E.wav',True)
            return E
        elif var==6:
            F=playsound('audio-alphabet/F.wav',True)
            return F
        elif var==7:
            G=playsound('audio-alphabet/G.wav',True)
            return G
        elif var==8:
            H=playsound('audio-alphabet/H.wav',True)
            return H
        elif var==9:
            I=playsound('audio-alphabet/I.wav',True)
            return I
        elif var==10:
            J=playsound('audio-alphabet/J.wav',True)
            return J
        elif var==11:
            K=playsound('audio-alphabet/K.wav',True)
            return K
        elif var==12:
            L=playsound('audio-alphabet/L.wav',True)
            return L
        elif var==13:
            M=playsound('audio-alphabet/M.wav',True)
            return M
        elif var==14:
            N=playsound('audio-alphabet/N.wav',True)
            return N
        elif var==15:
            O=playsound('audio-alphabet/O.wav',True)
            return O
        elif var==16:
            P=playsound('audio-alphabet/P.wav',True)
            return P
        elif var==17:
            Q=playsound('audio-alphabet/Q.wav',True)
            return Q
        elif var==18:
            R=playsound('audio-alphabet/R.wav',True)
            return R
        elif var==19:
            S=playsound('audio-alphabet/S.wav',True)
            return S
        elif var==20:
            T=playsound('audio-alphabet/T.wav',True)
            return T
        elif var==21:
            U=playsound('audio-alphabet/U.wav',True)
            return U
        elif var==22:
            V=playsound('audio-alphabet/V.wav',True)
            return V
        elif var==23:
            W=playsound('audio-alphabet/W.wav',True)
            return W
        elif var==24:
            X=playsound('audio-alphabet/X.wav',True)
            return X
        elif var==25:
            Y=playsound('audio-alphabet/Y.wav',True)
            return Y
        elif var==26:
            Z=playsound('audio-alphabet/Z.wav',True)
            return Z
```

Now this is the part where the application crashes.

```
class LetterAScreen(Screen):
    def on_enter(self):
        self.loader(
    def loader(self):
        self.identity()
        self.verifier()
    def identity(self):
        global where
        iden=Identifier()
        lol.fn_compare()  
    def verifier(self):
        iden=Identifier()
        global where
        count = 1
        while (count>0 and where != 1):
            self.identity()
            count=count+1
        iden.fn_verify()
```

I plan to have 26 screens, A-Z, all having the same kind of functions. However, I can't even progress with one. The problem here is when I enter the said screen, the app crashes and the memory and CPU overloads. What I tried to do in the code was for the `identity` function to run the `fn_compare` function. Then, the `verifier` class will then decide if the `global where variable` is equal to `1` or the letetr `A`. Once it becomes True, I tried to put the `fn_verify` function when the loop ends so that it only plays the sound when the `global where` variable matches to `1`.

What might be causing the crash and how do I solve this? I'm new to Python and Kivy and I really want to learn more. I hopw you could help me.

Comment: Please post the error or Kivy log.

Answer (score 0):

## Root Causes

1. In `class LetterAScreen()`, you have instantiated `class Identifier()` twice i.e. 2 or double instances. Once in method `identity()` and the other one in method `verifier()`
2. In method verifier(), it called method `self.identity()` in a loop. Each time through the loop, you are instantiating new instances of `class Identifier()`. Thus you ran out of memory.

## Solution

```
def loader(self):
    self.iden = Identifier()
    self.identity()
    self.verifier()

def identity(self):
    global where
    self.iden.fn_compare()

def verifier(self):
    global where
    count = 1
    while (count > 0 and where != 1):
        self.identity()
        count = count + 1
    self.iden.fn_verify()
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! I followed your instructions, but the app still crashes upon entering the Screen. Unfortunately, I don't have error logs to post because nothing displays in the shell. i don't know if the functions in my `class Identifier` is wrong or if it's a bug. Do you have anymore suggestions?

Comment: How did you run your app? Please post print screen.